# Problems with filehandles on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have a Windows 2008 R2 Server here (DC, File, Print, ...). Since a few weeks, one of our employes is reporting problems with the fileserver. She (and only she) has problems while trying to move or rename folders. Her client thinks that the folder is already in use. Does problems are occuring not always and not always at the same place.

I took a look on the server side, an sometimes I can see a connection to the filserver with an open file, mostly "Thumbs.db". But she has closed all opne windows and programs. Does anybody have a hint where I've to search for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the AV/Anti-Malware app(s) on all clients are set to not scan network drives. That can cause random, temporary locks that may clear by the time you check the server.

Comment: Good point. I'll check that. It shouldn't be that, beauce AV-Software is configured and managed from our server, so everybody should have the same AV configuration.

Comment: Looks like our Avira Professional is configured to ignore networkshares. I found Windows Defender, but I don't think he looks after networkshares. Last, but not least, I've found Adobe File Monitor (from Photoshop Elements), I've deactivated it. We'll see if this was the problem, but we have to wait, because the problem occurs not always and only after a certain time of working with the computer.